# Echo a variable outside of while loop in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, while-loop, advanced-custom-fields

I have a PHP while loop and I'm trying to echo the contents of `$child_i` outside of it, how can I do this?

```
<li>
    <div class="responsive-accordion-head"><span class="ico arrow-right"></span><?php the_sub_field('category_name'); ?> <span class="faq-counter">4 Questions</span></div>
        <?php if( have_rows('questions') ): $child_i = 0; ?>
            <!-- Trying to echo $child_i on the line below -->
            <div class="responsive-accordion-panel <?php echo($child_i); ?>">
                <?php while( have_rows('questions') ): the_row(); ?>
                    <div class="question">
                        <h6><?php the_sub_field('question'); ?></h6>    
                        <p><?php the_sub_field('answer'); ?></p>
                    </div>
                <?php $child_i++; endwhile; ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; //if( get_sub_field('items') ): ?>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: The $child_i value will continue to exist outside the loop, so you can just output it there. (Endwhile is PHP alternative syntax and signifies the end of the while loop started a little above it)

Comment: @GauravDave please [read docs](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php)

Comment: @GauravDave it ends the while loop...

Comment: Thanks everyone, I have not used endwhile before. Now, will everyone solve problem of @egr103

Comment: It is still better to use the old curlies (`{}`) than to use `:` and `endwhile`. Code editors don't support this syntax, which makes it diffucult to debug and to read. All code editors support curlies, which makes debug a breeze :-)

Answer (score 0):

can put the results into your own array then access it via its number

```
<li>
    <div class="responsive-accordion-head"><span class="ico arrow-right"></span><?php the_sub_field('category_name'); ?> <span class="faq-counter">4 Questions</span></div>
        <?php if( have_rows('questions') ): $child_i = 0; ?>
            <!-- Trying to echo $child_i on the line below -->
            <div class="responsive-accordion-panel <?php echo($child_i); ?>">
                <?php while( have_rows('questions') ): the_row(); ?>
                    <div class="question">
                        <h6><?php the_sub_field('question'); ?></h6>    
                        <p><?php the_sub_field('answer'); ?></p>
                    </div>
                <?php $results[] = $child_i; $child_i++; endwhile; ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; 
print_r($results);
//OR foreach($results as $result){echo $result;} 
//OR echo $result[1].$result[1]; //etc
//if( get_sub_field('items') ): ?>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Please make sure that your code is in a proper code block before posting

Comment: Am I able to grab the total values from that array?

Comment: foreach($results as $result){echo $result;} <--, or did you mean total? as in end($results); or total as in addition? foreach($results as $result){ $newvalue += $result;} echo $newvalue;

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to move your class inside your `while()` loop and then use the counter

Example

```
<li>
    <div class="responsive-accordion-head"><span class="ico arrow-right"></span><?php the_sub_field('category_name'); ?> <span class="faq-counter">4 Questions</span></div>
        <?php if( have_rows('questions') ): $child_i = 0; ?>
            <!-- Trying to echo $child_i on the line below -->
                <?php while( have_rows('questions') ): the_row(); ?>

            <div class="responsive-accordion-panel <?php echo ($child_i); ?>">

                    <div class="question">
                        <h6><?php the_sub_field('question'); ?></h6>    
                        <p><?php the_sub_field('answer'); ?></p>
                    </div>

             </div>

                <?php $child_i++; endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; //if( get_sub_field('items') ): ?>
    </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to insert

```
echo '<xmp>'; var_dump($child_i); echo '</xmp>';
```

instead of

```
echo($child_i);
```

($child_i can contain an empty string)

Comment: `$child_i` is a simple counter which returns an integer which you can just `echo`. It can never be an empty string, the OP started the counter of at `0`